# PHP: Database Connection Class Constructor Method

Tags: php, oop, class, database-connection

I'm new to OOP. Originally I was defining variables and assigning values to them within the class and outside of the constructor, but after an OOP lesson in Java today, I was told this is bad style and should be avoided.

Here is my original PHP database connection class that I mocked-up:

```
class DatabaseConnection {
    private $dbHost = "localhost";
    private $dbUser = "root";
    private $dbPass = "";
    private $dbName = "test";

    function __construct() {    
        $connection = mysql_connect($this->dbHost, $this->dbUser, $this->dbPass)
            or die("Could not connect to the database:<br />" . mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db($this->dbName, $connection) 
            or die("Database error:<br />" . mysql_error());
    }
}
```

Is the above considered okay? Or is the following a better way?

```
class DatabaseConnection {
    private $dbHost;
    private $dbUser;
    private $dbPass;
    private $dbName;

    function __construct() {
        $this->dbHost = "localhost";
        $this->dbUser = "root";
        $this->dbPass = "";
        $this->dbName = "test";

        $connection = mysql_connect($this->dbHost, $this->dbUser, $this->dbPass)
            or die("Could not connect to the database:<br />" . mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db($this->dbName, $connection) 
            or die("Database error:<br />" . mysql_error());
    }
}
```

What should I be focusing on to make sure I am understanding OOP correctly?

Comment: Let's forget about OOP for a moment. Shouldn't the values for host, user, password and dbname be stored in a configuration file?

Comment: @Aaron, check my updated answer. I added a few items for you to consider in your setup.

Comment: @JoniSalonen , who cares where they are stored ? The point is that they should be passed as parameters in constructor.

Comment: @tereško The user cares. In both of the examples the connection data is hardcoded in program code. It's a common requirement that data like this should be read from a user-friendly configuration file. This implies that either the DB unit has to read and parse the file, or you need a different unit to do it. If you use a different unit you have to design the interface between these units. On the other hand, if it's OK for the connection data to be hardcoded in the program, you don't need any such interface.

Comment: @JoniSalonen , are you implying that a `DatabaseConnection` class should be aware of the configuration ?

Comment: @tereško I'm implying that a conscious decision has to be made, weighing the pros and the cons of each option.

Comment: @JoniSalonen: I'd imply the opposite.  The connection class should not know about them or where to get them.  It should be told those values by the code that's constructing it.  Otherwise you're creating deeper artificial coupling between the database class and the configuration (preventing re-use and testing)...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, it's not going to run quite yet. You need to change your variables so that they match your connection params:

```
$dbHost = "localhost";
```

Should be

```
$this->dbHost = 'localhost';
```

I normally don't put my login params inside of the class at all. I would pass them into the constructor when the object is created. Use an outside config file so you can actually use this class on more than one build. :)

Update::

Okay, so here are a few little OOP configuration gold-nuggets that help you build a dynamic Database class.

- Check out http://redbeanphp.com/ It will allow you to do a psuedo ORM style of data modelling. Super easy to install, and ridiculously easy to get your database up and running. http://redbeanphp.com/manual/installing
- Create a configuration file that contains things like constants, template setups, common functions, and an **AUTOLOADER** Configuration files are key when working in version controlled environments. :)
- Build your Database class as an abstract class http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php

  ```
  abstract class Database
  {
    public function update()
    {
    }

    public function deactivate()
    {
    }

    public function destroy()
    {
    }

    //etc.
  }

  class MyAppObject extends Database
  {
  }
  ```
- Put all of your class files into a library folder, and then put your configuration file into that library. Now, to make your life easier you can use an autoloader function to bring your classes to life whenever you need them, without having to include any specific class. See below:

  ```
  //note: this is never explicitly instantiated
  //note: name your files like this: MyAppObject.class.php  
  function my_fancypants_autoloader( $my_class_name )
  {
    if( preg_match( "%^_(Model_)%", $my_class_name ) ) return;
    require_once( "$my_class_name.class.php" );
  }
  spl_autoload_register( 'my_fancypants_autoloader' );
  ```

  - Now all you have to do is include one configuration file in your .php files to access your classes.

Hope that points you in the right direction! Good luck!

Answer (score 10):

First of all: this is pointless.

You are creating an object wrapper for the 10+ year old `mysql_*` function. This php extension is no longer maintained and the process of deprecation has [already begun](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). You should not use this API for any new projects in 2012.

Instead you should learn how to use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysql) and work with [prepared statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement).

That said .. lets take a look at your code:

- Constructor should receive all the parameters required for creating new instance, parameters should not be hard-coded in the class definition. What if you need to work with two databases at the same time ?
- When connection is created, it should be stored in object's scope variable. Something along the lines of `$this->connection = mysql_conn...`. Instead you store it in local variable, which you *"loose"* right after constructor is done.
- You should not use `private` variables for everything. They are not visible to classes which would extend your original class. Unless it is intentional, you should choose `protected` for this.
- The  `or die('..')` bit most go. Do not stop the whole application if connection fails. Instead you should throw an [exception](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php), which then can be handled outside of the constructor.

Comment: If he wants to connect to another database he can specify the database name in he query...don't be such a dick man. geez

Comment: @michaelhanon did you actually looks at his code? Just naming connection will have no benefit. And you probably should read about [OCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle) to not sound like such a tool.

Comment: @michaelhanon I would have bashed far worse than terēsko did, specially those implying useless stuff in there comments ..

Answer (score 0):

Since your are only using them into the `__construct` method, you don't need them as class attributes. Only the `$connection` has to be kept for later use imho.

It might be much much better to not give any default values to those arguments but let them being set from the outside.

```
$db = new DatabaseConnection("localhost", "user", "password", "db");
```

They are plenty of PHP tools for that already, find them, read them and learn from that. First of all, use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) and what is true in Java isn't always true in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

The latter is probably better, but with an adjustment: pass some arguments to the constructor, namely the connection info.

Your first example is only useful if you've got one database connection and only if you're happy hard-coding the connection values (you shouldn't be).  The second example, if you add say, a `$name` parameter as an argument, could be used to connect to multiple databases:

I'm new to OOP. Originally I was defining variables and assigning values to them within the class and outside of the constructor, but after an OOP lesson in Java today, I was told this is bad style and should be avoided.

```
class DatabaseConnection {
    private $dbHost;
    private $dbUser;
    private $dbPass;
    private $dbName;

    function __construct($config) {
        // Process the config file and dump the variables into $config
        $this->dbHost = $config['host'];
        $this->dbName = $config['name'];
        $this->dbUser = $config['user'];
        $this->dbPass = $config['pass'];

        $connection = mysql_connect($this->dbHost, $this->dbUser, $this->dbPass)
            or die("Could not connect to the database:<br />" . mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db($this->dbName, $connection) 
            or die("Database error:<br />" . mysql_error());
    }
}
```

So using this style, you now have a more useful class.

Answer (score -1):

Here is mine and it works rather well:

```
class Database
{
   private static $_dbUser = 'user';
   private static $_dbPass = 'pwd';
   private static $_dbDB = 'dbname';
   private static $_dbHost = 'localhost';
   private static $_connection = NULL;

   /**
    * Constructor
    * prevents new Object creation
    */

   private function __construct(){
   }

   /**
    * Get Database connection
    * 
    * @return Mysqli
    */

   public static function getConnection() {
      if (!self::$_connection) {
     self::$_connection = @new mysqli(self::$_dbHost, self::$_dbUser, self::$_dbPass, self::$_dbDB);

         if (self::$_connection -> connect_error) {
            die('Connect Error: ' . self::$_connection->connect_error);
         }
      }
      return self::$_connection;
   }
}
```

By making the `__construct` empty, it prevents a new class being instantiated from anywhere.  Then, make the function static so now all I need to do to get my connection is `Database::getConnection()`  And this is all in an `include` file, in a password protected folder on the server and just included with each class file.  This will also check to see if a connection is already open before attempting another one.  If one is already established, it passes the open connection to the method.

Comment: and if at all possible (in most cases it **is** possible) don't use the `root` user!!!  If ever a security breach, your DB is toast.  Create a second account with minimal permissions.  My secondary account can't even delete records.  If I need to be able to delete records, I'll create another Database class, with a user with just that permission, and only call it for the methods I need.

Comment: If you use all-static classes, then it is not OOP. It's just same old procedural code with global variables. You just wrap it in a class, which acts like namespace.

Comment: And, please ! FFS, stop using the `@` operator, where it is not required. Hiding errors is usually the worst thing you can do.

Comment: I use it there because my users don't need to know that I couldn't establish a db connection specifically just to 'Try again later'.  This is the only instance I use @

Comment: Thats why we have `ini_set('dispaly_errors', false);` for the production code. User does not need to know, but **maintainer needs**. As for that "one connection" c**p, Please go and learn what [dependency injection](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RlfLCWKxHJ0) is ..

Answer (score -3):

```
<?php

    class config
    {
        private $host='localhost';
        private $username='root';
        private $password='';
        private $dbname='khandla';

        function __construct()
        {   
            if(mysql_connect($this->host,$this->username,$this->password))
            {
                echo "connection successfully";
            }
        }
        function db()
        {
            mysql_select_db($this->$dbname);
        }
    }

    $obj=new config();
?>
```

Comment: mysql_connect is discouraged: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php