# How to debug my PDO database class?

Tags: php, oop, pdo

After 10 years away from PHP coding, am getting back in the swing of things going through tutorials. I discovered things have changed, and PDO is the new standard to connect to MySQL.

I set up small projects. I am trying to build my own Class database, and things get all sideways, and I don't figure out why.

So here is my database class:

```
<?PHP

    $Db = new database; 

    class database
    {
        /////////////
        //Attributs//
        /////////////

        private $db_host;
        private $db_user;
        private $db_pass;
        private $db_name;
        private $bdd;

        /////////////////////
        // internal process//
        /////////////////////

        private function activateDB()
        {
            $this->checkList();
            $this->dbInitilisation();
            $this->dbConnection();
        }

        ////////////////////////
        //Check Websiteconfig//
        ////////////////////////

        private function checkList()
        {
            if(!file_exists('website-config.ini')){
                die('missing configuration file.');
            }
        }

        ///////////
        //Db init//
        ///////////

        private function dbInitilisation()
        {
            // Load config file for database connection info
            $config = parse_ini_file("website-config.ini");

            $this->db_host=$config['db_host'];
            $this->db_user=$config['db_login'];
            $this->db_pass=$config['db_password'];
            $this->db_name=$config['db_name'];
        }

        /////////////////
        //Db connection//
        /////////////////

        private function dbConnection()
        { 
            try
                {
                    $this->bdd = new PDO('mysql:host='.$this->db_host.';dbname='.$this->db_name.';charset=utf8', 'root', '');
                    $this->bdd->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);             
                }
                catch (Exception $e)
                {
                    die('error '.$e);
                }
        }


        public function dbQuery($user_query, $parameters)
        {
            $this->activateDB();

            $query = $this->bdd->prepare($user_query);
            $query->execute($parameters);
            $query->fetch();
            return $query;

        }

    }
?>
```

and, here is how I am calling it:

```
$values[':user_id']='1';
$result=($Db->dbQuery('SELECT user_username FROM user WHERE user_id = :user_id',$values));
print_r($result);
```

When I was not using pdo, and writing my function like normal, I had what I wanted. Now, not any more.

Does anyone has a clue on what I am doing wrong? Do you have any kind of comment on how to improve my overall stuff?

PS: I did read around before coming here (like here: http://php.net/manual/fr/pdostatement.fetch.php (I thought my issue were maybe with the type of fetch, but again, when not in OOP, my code runs ok as it is.) Or here [PHP: Database Connection Class Constructor Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9937953/php-database-connection-class-constructor-method) but the solution give here is to go on someone else code library, and not allowing to understand what I am actually doing wrong.

Comment: I have. Here you go: [Your first database wrapper's childhood diseases](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/common_mistakes)

Comment: Why do you say you're doing something wrong -do you get an error? Is there a silent failure?

Comment: yes the failure is obvious - a premature fetch

Comment: You are trying to abstract the abstraction - rarely a good idea. But we all made that mistake :-)

Comment: The general direction you are going to is right. But the implementation is not that good. Refer to the two answers linked at the top of your question for the good examples

Comment: @Joni; yes, no error as such, just that my result is the actuall query in an array.
but as @YourCommonSense pointed out sharpy, it s teh exact ame issue as described here : [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43104562/how-do-i-parse-object-data-from-mysql-database-using-php-pdo[link].

Comment: YourCommonSense, I have to admit tho, english not being my frist language what you mean by to early fetch :) it comes last in my chain of actions. 
and on the same level "abstract the abstraction" seems very poetic @arkascha, but doesn't talk much to me.  That said thank you al, it seems that i have lot so freading to do ,a d with answers that match my need :D

Comment: What I meant simply is: PDO already is a perfectly fine abstraction layer sitting on top of your database. Though intuitively one starts implementing some database wrapper class it actually does not offer that much advantages over using PDO directly, but instead reduces your flexibility.

Comment: @arkascha, well, i have a perfect flexibilty right there :) it sjus the posiiton of teh fetch that get on me :)
That said, i was reading a very interesting post saying that one of the very interesting purpose of "classing" your pdo, is that if you were to change of sql engine, you would have actually no change to make to your scatered sql request... fyi

Comment: I'd say: that reads like you should get a good night full of sleep and lots of water to drink over the next hours ;-)

Comment: @arkascha, just finish my debug!! :D i have it up and running. I lllisten to you and going to bed. night